# Is there a specific treatment for DOM object in IE8?

Tags: javascript, element

I have this function declared:

```
Object.prototype.append = Array.prototype.append = append = function( tag ){
alert( this )
...
}
```

It supposed to append "tag" element after a DOM element or an array of objects.
Now, when I call it after an array of two elements - everything works well, I get "[object HTMLDivElement,object HTMLDivElement]" thtown by `alert` for, but when it's called by a single DOM element IE8 throws that the object does not support this option or method and even the alert is not executed.

Comment: What's the implementation code? Do you try and access a `length` property?

Comment: It won't access the function. The implementation code has nothing to do with it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOM element does not necessarily inherit from the Javascript `Object`.  You cannot count on that.  It might work in some places, but as you have encountered, it does not work everywhere.

You can add a method to an existing DOM object after it's been created, but this can sometimes cause issues.  Libraries like prototype that use to extend built-in objects are moving away from that behavior and libraries like jQuery and YUI avoid it entirely.

I would suggest that you are better off using a utility function rather than an add-on DOM method or a wrapper object like jQuery does.

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect DOM elements to inherit properties from built-in ECMAScript constructors, not only becaue they don't in some browsers but because there is nothing to say that they must.

It is also not good to extend built-in prototypes as it messes with for..in iteration and may conflict with built-in methods, particularly with a common name like *append*.

#### Edit

I assume you are doing something like the following (which is why implementation **is** important):

```
Object.prototype.append = Array.prototype.append = append = function( tag ){

  alert(typeof this);  // object in browsers that support native inheritance for DOM objects

  if (typeof this == 'object') {
    // assume that object is a DOM element, create a tag element and append
    // it to `this`

  } else {
    // assume object is an array of DOM elements so create one tag element for
    // each and append it.
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('foo');

  // Call append on a DOM element
  alert(el.append);  // function in Firefox
                     // undefined in IE
  if (el.append) el.append();

  // Call append on an Array
  var array = [el];
  alert(array.append);

  if (array.append) array.append();
}
```

The second part works in IE because *append* is called as a method of an array, it fails in the first case because the code expects a DOM element to inherit from Object.prototype, which it doesn't.

Comment: The problem is the script works for arrays of elements, but not for a single. Nevertheless, I'd changed the name of the function but that is not the problem, as it turned out.

Comment: I didn't say the name was the problem, only that extending built-in objects was not a good idea beacuse it **might** clash with built-in methods. The problem is that I think you are expecting DOM elements to inherit from Object.prototype - you should not.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript **Object.prototype** is for **[object object]**, it is plain object, and Array.prototype is for Array. in your case, you can append a element to some array, in my mind, you use something like [XXX] syntax, when you append a DOM element, it actually call  **Array.prototype.append** method. but as a single DOM element, the DOM element is **[object HTMLDivElement]**, not plain object **[object object]**, that's why you get a error there.